# How can I make Air remember the location of last opened file?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, filepath

All the walkthroughs I've seen specify either desktop, local files as the initial view when calling [browseForOpen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html).

Is there a way to have the air application remember the last location a file was loaded from and default back there?

If necessary I suppose the path could be written to the local db, but even still, I do not know how to get the filepath of the loaded file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [File.nativePath](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#nativePath) and [File.resolvePath](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#resolvePath%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

A few years later, perhaps, but thought this might help someone in the future.

```
var file:File = new File();
file.browseForOpen("Open");
```

This will open the last location.